# Python function references

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I am trying to mock a function and decorate its behaviour. For this I have to get the original function behaviour, save it and add it to a wrap function. Should look like this:

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    def wrap_function(arg):
        return "potato" + original_function(arg)

    package.original_function = Mock(wraps= wrap_function)
```

This code works, but any of the following variants does not.

1)

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    def wrap_function(arg):
        return "potato" + package.original_function(arg)

    original_function = Mock(wraps= wrap_function)
```

2)

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    def wrap_function(arg):
        return "potato" + package.original_function(arg)

    package.original_function = Mock(wraps= wrap_function)
```

3)

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    def wrap_function(arg):
        return "potato" + original_function(arg)

    original_function = Mock(wraps= wrap_function)
```

I have imported both

```
import package
from package import original_function
```

Could anybody explain to me why the first one does work, and the rest don't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why does the first one works?

It works because you're monkey-patching the function at the module level and that modified value is going to stay till the module stays in `sys.modules`.

Basically when you do:

```
from package import original_function
```

This adds a new reference to the `original_function` object in current namespace and now if you do something like:

```
package.original_function = 1
```

you're updating that module's namespace to make `original_function` point to 1, but this doesn't mean that the already imported `original_function` should change as well.

### Why the others failed?

1. `original_function = Mock(wraps= wrap_function)` defines a new local variable and that won't have any affect on either `package.original_function` or `original_function`.
2. `package.original_function = Mock(wraps= wrap_function)`: The mocking was correct but then we are calling the same mocked function again instead of the actual function in `wrap_function`.
3. `original_function = Mock(wraps= wrap_function)`: Same as 1, we defined a local variable and the same function will be used `wrap_function` as well because it lies its enclosing scope.